# Format PostgreSQL into JSON

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am reading a PostgreSQL, and would like eventually to convert this into a nice JSON.
The output from the PostgreSQL query contains e.g. "Decimal('value')" which I am trying to clean away. Unfortunately the values disappears during this process, and I am not sure how to re-write it so they remain.

**Code:**

```
columns = ("parameter", "timestamp", "epoch")
inputRecords = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    inputRecords.append(dict(zip(columns,row)))
inputRecordsCleaned = [tuple(str(item) for item in t) for t in inputRecords]
inputRecordsJson = json.dumps(inputRecordsCleaned, indent=2)
```

**Output:**

```
inputRecords = [{'parameter': Decimal('-0.9'), 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 12, 16, 48), 'epoch': 1583929008}]

inputRecordsCleaned = [('parameter', 'timestamp', 'epoch')]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
inputRecordsCleaned = [('parameter': '-0.9', 'timestamp': '2020, 3, 11, 12, 16, 48', 'epoch': '1583929008')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decimal.Decimal` can be easily converted to `str`s. You might deliver `str` to `json.dumps` as `default` that is:

```
import datetime
import json
from decimal import Decimal
inputRecords = [{'parameter': Decimal('-0.9'), 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 11, 12, 16, 48), 'epoch': 1583929008}]
records_json = json.dumps(inputRecords, default=str)
print(records_json)
```

Output:

```
[{"parameter": "-0.9", "timestamp": "2020-03-11 12:16:48", "epoch": 1583929008}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the comprehension you need is:

```
inputRecordsCleaned = [{k: str(v) for k,v in record.items()} for record in inputRecords]
```

With the given sample, it give:

```
[{'parameter': '-0.9', 'timestamp': '2020-03-11 12:16:48', 'epoch': '1583929008'}]
```